# How to change the UiSearchbar height ,width , color and Uitextfield Height in UISearchBar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I Want to change `UISearchBar`.The `textfield height and width`.
My question is how to change the `UiSearchbar height ,width , color` and `Uitextfield Height` in `UISearchBar` in `iphone`?

Any Idea or Suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the height of the textfield from the source code of the xib. For opening a xib in source code format you need to right click on the xib file and then select "Open as source code". On that code search for the textfield and change the height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color itself in storyboard under attributes inspector, however, to set the x,y,width & height I use this...

Firstly create your UISearchBar object:

'.h'

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

And then in the viewdidload/willappear put this code

'.m'

```
self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(34, 244.5, 306, 30);
```

Make adjustments as you deem necessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)setSearchIconToFavicon 
{
    // Really a UISearchBarTextField, but the header is private.
[[mySearchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.0];

UITextField *searchField = nil;`enter code here`
for (UIView *subview in mySearchBar.subviews) 
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) 
    {
        searchField = (UITextField *)subview;
        break;
    }
}
if(!(searchField == nil)) 
{
    searchField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchFieldBG.png"] ];
    [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    searchField.frame = CGRectMake(4, 5, 285, 50); 
}
}
```

Comment: This code is not calling, where I put this code and how to call this code?

Comment: uiseach bar has delegate methods

Comment: - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

Comment: Cant understand as I am new in iPhone. Please help.

Answer (score -2):

```
[searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,80,30)];
```

Hope it helpfull to you :)

Comment: please post some code so i can understand how you use the search bar:)